# Copying contacts from one source to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook, icloud

I'm trying to copy contacts between my Local contact source and the iCloud contact source and I'm not seeing any results. This code executes without error and seems like it should work, but I don't see the newly created contacts afterward. Anyone see any issues with it?

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

ABRecordRef abSourceSource = ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID(addressBook, kABSourceTypeLocal);
ABRecordRef abDestinationSource = ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID(addressBook, kABSourceTypeCardDAV);

CFArrayRef sourceContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(addressBook, abSourceSource);
CFArrayRef destinationContacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource(addressBook, abDestinationSource);

ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(abDestinationSource, ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(sourceContacts));
ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(abSourceSource, ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(destinationContacts)));

ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, NULL);
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a more fundamental problem - you are not calling ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID properly. The 2nd parameter it takes is an int that specifies the record id of a particular source in your address book. You are passing it a constant that describes the type of a particular source.

The constant you are passing, kABSourceTypeCardDav is always 4. However, the record id of the iCloud source in a user's address book can be something very different.

What you need to do is enumerate all the sources and test their types, like so:

```
NSArray *allSources = (NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);

for (int i = 0; i < allSources.count; i++) {
    ABRecordRef src = [allSources objectAtIndex:i];
    NSNumber *stObj = (NSNumber*)ABRecordCopyValue(src, kABSourceTypeProperty);
    ABSourceType st = (ABSourceType)[stObj intValue];

    if (st == kABSourceTypeCardDAV) {
        int recordID = ABRecordGetRecordID(src);
        break;
    }
}
```

Then you could use recordID as the argument to the first function

Comment: And just to confuse matters more- 

Not all "kABSourceTypeCardDAV" address books are iCloud. You need to also check that kABSourceTypeNameProperty is "Card", or you may end up accidentally trying to save to a Facebook address book (which won't end well, as that is read-only) or to a Google or Yahoo address book, all of which can use CardDAV.

Also note that if the user has not yet set up iCloud in their device, they will have a local address book instead, which becomes their iCloud address book when they configure iCloud.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to add the records with ABAddressBookAddRecord. Here is my working example:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef abSource = ABAddressBookGetSourceWithRecordID(addressBook, kABSourceTypeLocal);
NSURL *theURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"some.vcf"];
NSData *vCardData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
NSLog(@"data %@", vCardData);
NSArray *createdPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABPersonCreatePeopleInSourceWithVCardRepresentation(abSource, (__bridge CFDataRef)vCardData);
NSLog(@"createdPeople %@", createdPeople);
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
bool ok;
for (id person in createdPeople) {
    error = NULL;
    ok = ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, (__bridge ABRecordRef)person, &error);
    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"add err %@", error);  
        break;
    } 
}
if (ok) {
    error = NULL;
    BOOL isSaved = ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
    if (isSaved) {
        NSLog(@"saved..");
    }
    if (error != NULL) {
        NSLog(@"ABAddressBookSave %@", error);
    } 
}
CFRelease(addressBook);
```

Comment: Hi jazzbox, thanks! Let me give this a shot a let you know. Rob