# Using VCards with ABAddressBook in iOS 5.0/XCode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, abaddressbook, vcf-vcard

I am trying to save a copy of all the entries in the address book, save it to a file as vcards, and then retrieve that file (or a version of that file) and add them back to the address book when I need them, in a backing up context. I know this question has been asked before, but for the life of me (and my newbish programming skills) I can not get it to work:

```
- (void)grabContacts
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef contacts = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSData *vcards = (NSData *)ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(contacts);

    [vcards autorelease];

    NSError *error;
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];


    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
    NSString *folderPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.dat"];

   [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:vcards toFile:filePath];    

    NSLog(@"Documents directory: %@",
      [fileMgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: folderPath error:&error]);

   CFRelease(addressBook);
 }
```

I used the solution posted in [Copying contacts from one source to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898238/copying-contacts-from-one-source-to-another) for the receiving end, but it doesn't work and due to the vague documentation on Apple's side I have wracked my brain for no result.

Thanks in advance.

S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found my problem. I did not unarchive the files when I restored them. Silly me gets what silly me deserves for programming without copious amounts of alcohol.

Comment: Congrats on the solution! When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success. Cheers~